# How to get the context without any request, session, etc?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

I have a method in a class, which *doesn't get* anything which could be usable to get the actual servlet context. Practically, it is like

```
public String getSomething() { ... }
```

But to calculate the result, I need the actual, thread-specific servlet structures.

I think, somewhere in the deepness in the application context, some like a thread-specific storage should exist, which could be reached by calling static methods of some system class.

I am in a tomcat6 servlet container, but Spring is also available if it is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An obvious solution would be to pass the context as a parameter, since you're obviously running the code where the context is normally available.

If for some reason you feel that this is not something you can do (I'd like to hear the reason for that), another way would be to create a servlet filter that would then create for example a `ThreadLocal<ServletContext>`.

Comment: would a `ThreadLocal` really be needed? AFAIK, `ServletContext` is defined only once per VM

Comment: @epoch Maybe different web applications have different ServletContext?

Comment: Thank you very much - finally I did your first idea: I gave the servletContext in a new setter to the bean. Maybe it is not the most beatuful solution, but surely it was the simplest and most platform-independent.

Comment: @Kayaman: that is required when you have some part of common code in a diferent API/library project, and you have polymorphed constructors in that library.

Answer (score 10):

Add a [`ServletContextListener`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/) to your `web.xml`. This will be called when your webapp is loaded. In the `contextInitialized()` method you can store the `ServletContext` in a static variable for example for later use. Then you will be able to access the `ServletContext` in a static way:

```
class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public static ServletContext context;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        context = sce.getServletContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        context = null;
    }

}
```

Add it to `web-xml` like this:

```
<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.something.MyListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

And you can access it from anywhere like this:

```
public String getSomething() {
    // Here you have the context:
    ServletContext c = MyListener.context;
}
```

**Note:**

You might want to store it as `private` and provide a `getter` method, and also check for `null` value before using it.

Answer (score 6):

If you have no pointer to something useful, the only way I know would be to have a static attribute in a class that contains current ServletContext. It is trivial with a `ServletContextListener`:

```
@WebListener
public class ServletContextHolder implements ServletContextListener {
    private static ServletContext servletContext;

    public static ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return servletContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        servletContext = null;
    }    
}
```

Then from anywhere you use

```
ServletContextHolder.getServletContext();
```

If you use Spring, you can also use the `RequestContextHolder` to gain access to current request (on from there to anything you need)

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                                 .getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

Of course if works that way in servlet application and not in portlet ones - you would have to use PortletRequestAttributes and finaly get a PortletRequest

Answer (score 1):

You can autowire servlet context as given below

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;
```